# Java script file not functioning in a rendered HTML file using express

Tags: javascript, html, express

I might have wrote my title incorrectly, but my problem is when i render it using ExpressJS the functionality i had in my HTML file doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a minimal reproducible example. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please elaborate?
What error are you getting?

Maybe, you are loading and executing the script before your page loads.
In that case, your JavaScript will fail to get objects from the DOM (because there is nothing in it).

Try using [defer](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/) when you load your scripts.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Lets say I want my script to get an alert when a button is pressed, when i would load the html page normally it works, but when loading it in expressJS it doesn't

Comment: HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Sharing Web App</title>
    <script src="C:/users/Jason/Desktop/JavaScript/Personal Projects/FileSharingService/webserver.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test-Btn">Test</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Express Server:
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var logger = require("morgan");
var path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var router = express.Router();
var port = 8888;
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Webserver error")
    }else{
        console.log(`Webserver has been deployed and listening on port ${port}, using Express`);
        router.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
        })
    }
})

Comment: app.js:

const test = document.getElementById("test-Btn");

addEventListener('click', ()=>{console.log("pressed")})

Comment: In your HTML file: <script src="C:/users/Jason/Desktop/JavaScript/Personal Projects/FileSharingService/webserver.js" async>
Replace async with defer. What async does that as soon as your script loads, it gets executed. On the other hand, defer pushed the execution after the HTML has been parsed.
Also, you may also want to use alert instead of console.log in your event listener and add your event listener to the button as -
app.js: const test = document.getElementById("test-Btn"); test.addEventListener('click', ()=>{alert("pressed")})

Comment: I have tried that it still doesn't work when I use Express to load the HTML page

Comment: I saw there is an error in your app.js code. Did you fix that?
Use - app.js: const test = document.getElementById("test-Btn"); test.addEventListener('click', ()=>{alert("pressed")})

Comment: When you are importing your script in HTML, try a path relative to your HTML file. For example, <script src="app.js" defer>

Comment: I just tried it and it also doesn't work, and do you understand what I'm trying to do by the way? I could elaborate some more.

Comment: Whenever I open the HTML file normally, the JS file does what it's supposed to do correctly. But when hosting the HTML file on my IP the JS file doesn't seem to be even loaded.

Comment: Yes, please. Also, it would be very helpful if you push your code to a github repo

Comment: Sure I'll do that too

Comment: https://github.com/JasonGH17/TestApp

I have added a 7zip and normal zip file, both containing the same files inside

Comment: You don't need to upload zip files to GitHub. You should always commit files and not compressed folders as other people can't see them.

Comment: I was able to solve it with a few changes. 1. In index.html use this - <script src="/app.js" defer></script> 2. in webserver.js add this line after app.use('/', router); - app.use(express.static('public')); and last 3. The name of your public folder should not be 'Public' (probably a typo)

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you so much for your help.